# What does the Greek "E"-like symbol mean?

Tags: notation

I have a simple question: what does the following mean?

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n$$

Comment: That is a capital Sigma (from the Greek alphabet).  It stands for "Sum".

Comment: @lulu thanks i have something to search on now.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) is a good place to start.

Comment: In this case, with $k=0$ below it and $n$ above, it means that the expression to the right of $\sum$ should be evaluated for $k=0, 1, 2, \ldots, n$ and then summed. For example,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} x^k = x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots + x^n$$

Comment: I'm very confused why you call it "[romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_alphabet)".

Comment: One thing to note is that even though it is similar to the Latin character E, it has nothing to do with it, and makes the same sound as the Latin character "S".

Comment: This symbol is required to denote summations when the number of terms is too large for explicit expansion, or when it is variable (so impossible to write down). You have a similar symbol for products, using the capital pi letter: $\prod$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This symbol is a Greek letter called (capital) sigma. It's used to denote sums. The definition is

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = a_1+\cdots+a_n.
$$

For example:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^6 1 = \underbrace{1+\cdots+1}_{\text{6 times}} = 6
$$

or 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4 i = 1 + 2 +3+4 = 10.
$$

Comment: One could add that in typed math, the summation sign $\sum$ and the capital Sigma $\Sigma$ are rarely _exactly_ the same. I'm not sure how widespread this is for handwriting though (I have different symbols, but some colleagues definitely haven't).